# The Windows shutdown sound task I created is cut off

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, task-manager, system-sounds

I am doing a little project to challenge myself as I love messing around with computers. A project I started long ago was to try and create a shutdown sound for my Windows 10 OS on my computer. I did indeed successfully pull that off by creating a task in task manager to play the sound at shutoff. However, the sound is cut off most times before fully playing. I think it is because Windows 10 shuts down pretty quickly and is not made for a shutdown sound, since the feature was removed a long time ago.

Since I am stuck here, I am wondering if anyone have any ideas on how to make it always play the full sound and prevent it from getting cut off.

Comment: Should in theory be possible to create a powershell or vbscript script and use gpedit.msc computer configuration, shutdown script and link to your script. This ensures that the script is run after the user logged out, then waits with fully shutting down until the script finishes. This is usually done to facilitate making backups. Might be that the audio drivers are closed at this point, and sound is no longer possible.

Comment: Is it possible to create a task to run that command at shutdown to delay it when shutting down normally?

Comment: Its not possible to delay a shutdown. I tried that myself when programming something in vb.net, but since Windows 8 and up, the shutdown is somewhat forced, and delaying it will result in a message saying: this app is preventing windows from shutting down, but it is then quickly dismissed by windows and it shuts down anyway.